# cross validation with pipe line in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pipeline, apache-spark-mllib, cross-validation, apache-spark-ml

Cross Validation outside from pipeline.

```
val naivebayes
val indexer
val pipeLine = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(indexer, naiveBayes))

val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder()
   .addGrid(naiveBayes.smoothing, Array(1.0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5))
   .build()
val crossValidator = new CrossValidator().setEstimator(pipeLine)
   .setEvaluator(new MulticlassClassificationEvaluator)
   .setNumFolds(2).setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)

val crossValidatorModel = crossValidator.fit(trainData)

val predictions = crossValidatorModel.transform(testData)
```

Cross Validation inside pipeline

```
val naivebayes
val indexer

// param grid for multiple parameter
val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder()
   .addGrid(naiveBayes.smoothing, Array(0.35, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5))
   .build()

// validator for naive bayes
val crossValidator = new CrossValidator().setEstimator(naiveBayes)
   .setEvaluator(new MulticlassClassificationEvaluator)
   .setNumFolds(2).setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)

// pipeline to execute compound transformation
val pipeLine = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(indexer, crossValidator))

// pipeline model
val pipeLineModel = pipeLine.fit(trainData)

// transform data
val predictions = pipeLineModel.transform(testData)
```

So i want to know which way is better and its pro & cons.

For both functions, i am getting same result and accuracy. Even second approach is little bit faster than first.

Answer (score 0):

As per a training I attended - this should be the best practice :

```
cv = CrossValidator(estimator=lr,..)
pipelineModel = Pipeline(stages=[idx,assembler,cv])
cv_model= pipelineModel.fit(train)
```

This way your pipeline would fit only once and not with each recurring run with the param_grid which makes it run faster.
Hope this helps!